# Symfony2 gives blank page

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, symfony

Symfony 2 dies and gives me blank page. Disclaimer: I hate blank pages. Anyway, how do I find out what went wrong; why it died; why there's no error?

Checking the `dev.log` it gives me useless info:

```
[2011-08-05 08:41:33] doctrine.DEBUG: UPDATE accTransactions SET report_id = ? WHERE id = ? ([8163,2941852])
[2011-08-05 08:41:33] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.view" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelView".
[2011-08-05 08:41:33] event.DEBUG: Listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelView" stopped propagation of the event "kernel.view".
[2011-08-05 08:41:33] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse".
[2011-08-05 08:41:33] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse".
[2011-08-05 08:41:33] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler::onKernelResponse".
[2011-08-05 08:41:33] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\CacheListener::onKernelResponse".
[2011-08-05 08:41:33] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse".
[2011-08-05 08:41:35] event.DEBUG: Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse".
```

The `php_error.log` and other do not have an error.

I'm running an update on a large table, and doing about 1500+ queries per request (taking about 15sec). I assume the death of PHP has something to do with Doctrine2 then. It's very unstable, in that it start to die when the number of transactions seems to increase... I have to admin I expected much more from an ORM, not just blank deaths.

Is there a db log file or something that can give me an error? Anything to work with besides doing 1 transaction at a time, because that'll take 13,333 hours... It's a very basic update (just adding that one relation) if you look at the first log entry.

I'm running PHP 5.3.2 with APC

I've also noticed that when the function gets to the flush command at the bottom, it successfully executes it.
Thus, I assume it's only SF2 now that does not render the view successfully?

Comment: You have blank page EVEN in dev environment ? (use the app_dev.php file).

Have you take a look at the profiler ? (you can search for old request and then take a look at all the dev logs)

Comment: (stupid question) can you try to add ini_set('display_errors', 1); at the beginning of app_dev.php ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help with php blank page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816404/help-with-php-blank-page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are batch processing in Doctrine2 then your entity manager will be growing and you are breaching you PHP memory limit.

http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-batch-processing.html

You are creating thousands of objects and this is growing with each cycle.

You need to be careful when batch processing with an ORM that you eliminate memory leaks. An ORM is not always the best tool for this job but it CAN be used if you are careful with what you are doing.

Comment: your link is broken: http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-batch-processing.html

Answer (score 1):

try to delete these folders : 
- cache
- logs

and reload your page.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I cannot leave a comment below their posts, which is why I created an answer. Although, I did find the solution I was looking for. The problem was coming from the cache folder. A php bin/console cache:warmup did the trick. And to answer the question, I think while trying to clear the cache (folder) some files are not regenerated such classes.php, or classes.meta.php and that causes an internal server error which leads the web profiler not to be able to show itself or the errors. And that happened after I installed Symfony 2.5 and the Sonata Admin Bundle. Hope it helps.

Comment: In my case clearing the cache itself did not solve the problem. But the console would output the issue after executing the command. TWIG was exhausting the allowed memory size in ...Environment.php : eval()'d code on line 223 when I was trying to access a SonataAdminBundle list view.

Comment: I agree, it takes a lot of memory. Hope you found a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should turn on and look at your MySQL query log. On Debian Linux you should edit file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and edit it so it should have a look something similar to

```
[mysqld]
# ...

# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log             = 1
log_error                = /var/log/mysql/error.log
```

So you'll be able to view it realtime by `tail -F /var/log/mysql/mysql.log`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "cache: false" to twig in your config file for your environment.
Solve me.