# Opencart module issue

Tags: php, opencart

I'm trying to install Import Export module in open cart and I was able to get the menu coming out from the admin area but when I click on it, it returns a blank page. Is this something to do with token or something else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help with php blank page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/816404/help-with-php-blank-page)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the permission for the access.

For doing so follow the steps:

1. System->Users->User Group
2. Click on Edit relative to the user group you want to give the access (in my case its Top Administrator)
3. Select the permission "**tool/export**" in both "**Access Permission**" and "**Modify Permission**"
4. Click on Save.

Now you will have the access to the Import/Export Tool.