# Why does my PHP do nothing, show a blank page?

Tags: php, html

Why did my PHP just stop working?

Several things I did all at once that may have broke it:

1. Put jquery in without the jquery script included, but with jquery within javascript tags.
2. Created a stylesheet (which was working, but then I added a :before style and jquery and the php stopped working).
3. Changed white space within PHP code.
4. Put `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` at top, but then removed it and no change.

I expect a list of every folder and subfolder, but get a page with just the title, and Chrome shows me the php tags are within HTML comments (not sure if normal, never had php just not work).

**Issue was: filetype not ANSI.**

PHP:

```
<?php

function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            echo '<li>'.$ff;
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}


?>
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
</title>

<?php include("find.php"); ?>

</head>
<body>

<h2>Folders</h2>

<?php listFolderFiles('../');?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What errors do you get? What are you expecting but not seeing?

Comment: "Not working" is a broad term...

Comment: I expect a list of every folder and subfolder, but get a page with just the title, and Chrome shows me the php tags are within HTML comments (not sure if normal, never had php just not work).

Comment: maybe file is another format than ANSI?

Comment: Just this page. How about a phpinfo test script? What does the IIS server config thingy/registry say about PHP?

Comment: I think the ANSI thing might be my problem, out of the clear blue my text editor asked me if I wanted to keep the filetype so I assumed it had got changed.

Comment: What is the file extension you used on your HTML page? Did you use .html or .php?

Comment: Hey Mihai lorga, that fixed my issue, thanks, I had forgotten the filetype had an issue, it wasn't ANSI so I changed it and it works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info - look for 'I have a typical "does not work" problem. What should I do before asking a question?'

Comment: Check your PHP errors? http://stackoverflow.com/a/816411/339535

Comment: @MihaiIorga You should post the comment as a full answer, that way anyone searching will see this post has been answered and not skip it over if they're having the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your file is saved other than ANSI, because PHP cannot run on an UNICODE file.
try to open your file with your favorite editor and when you save ... make sure you save it as ANSI.